# Question about libvirt autostart and virtual manager

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualization, iso, libvirt

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04

I installed kvm and virtual manager and created a guest OS. Everything worked fine until I rebooted my pc. After reboot libvirt was not running despite of init script inside /etc/init.d 
If I start it manually it works. It's just annoying to do it manually every time. 
Is there a way I can debug why my libvirt fails to start automatically?

Second question:

As I said I'm using virtual manager to create and run my guest OS. Initially I installed my first os (Windows 7) from .iso file on USB drive, and when I disconnected that drive after guest OS installation, virtual manager complained about missing .iso file. Basically it fails to start without .iso.. If I plug back that USB drive - it works. Is it how it's suppose to be? I was thinking that once you installed your guest OS on a virtual hardrive space, you don't need .iso file any more..

Would appreciate any addition information on that topic.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Merely having the initscript isn't enough; upstart also needs to know that it has to be started.

It doesn't need the .iso anymore, but you haven't told it that. Push the "Disconnect" button.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a virtual bridge problem. Libvirt was trying to start before bridge was created. So I modified upstart script (/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf) to include addition check:

start on (runlevel [2345] and net-device-up IFACE=virbr1)

As for .iso issue I removed cdrom section using virsh edit VMNAME (which was pointing to my .iso file on USB drive) and it works just fine now.

Thanks for feedback on this question.